# Bootstrap hidden-sm-down not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boostrap 3. Why the `<div>` with `hidden-sm-down` is still visible when I resize the page on my laptop? I want to hide those two images on small devices in order to have a different menu.

```
<div class="row">                 
    <div class="col-md-7 left">
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-md-2">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-2">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-2">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm-down wave">
        <img src="img/ondina.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right">
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-md-6">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li  class="col-md-6">
                <a href="">Text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm-down right-border">
        <img src="img/menu-right.png"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Jaqen said, if you use Bootrstrap 3, you should use `hidden-sm` instead.

Also, if you want to hide the image on small screen, you have to add `hidden-xs`.

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fLrkwbk5/)

Answer (score 26):

Actually, `hidden-sm-down` won't work with Bootstrap 4 and above
(there use `d-none` instead of `hidden-sm-down`, and use `d-sm-none` instead of `hidden-sm-up`,
see also [understanding-details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610086/8740349)).

With BS4, display utility classes are completely changed. Use this format instead;

```
.d-{breakpoint}-{value}
```

More information ; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Strange that the Bootstrap 4 docs say to use OP's .hidden-sm-down, but this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For BS4, yes this is the correct way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You mention you use Bootstrap 3

Use [`hidden-sm`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) instead of `hidden-sm-down` which belongs to [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities)

**On a side note:**

You also mention:

> I want to hide those two images on small devices in order to have a different menu.

`hidden-sm` will hide the element on small screens such as iPad. To hide on extra small screens (such as Phones < 768px) add `hidden-xs`.

Take a look at the Bootstrap sizes table [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, you can utilize the following:

**Hidden only on small screens**

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hidden on screens smaller than lg</div>
```

**Visible only on small screens**

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">visible on small screens</div>
```