# Bootstrap 4 - hide on xs and sm not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating xs view for my app, and my problem is, when i want to hide one div on small and extra small devices this extra small is not working, i followed bootstrap 4 documentation, and i don't know why this is not working.

```
<div class="headers">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-5">Produkt</div>
          <div class="col-2 d-sm-none d-md-block d-flex justify-content-start">Cena</div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center">Ilość</div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-end">Wartość</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to put on second div:

> d-none d-md-block

Show when screen is on md mode. When i set this on sm and xs is not hidding. When i add only d-sm-none to this line it's working well but not on xs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because you should use `d-none` instead of `d-flex`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-5">Produkt</div>
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-start">Cena</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center">Ilość</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-end">Wartość</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/XUSWoSdFcP

**Related:**
[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4/45844579)

Comment: Wrong, the "`d-flex`" and/or "`d-none`" classes can never override "`d-sm-none`" or "`d-md-block`" classes, because the way CSS override mechanism works, it prefers styles written later in CSS-file (so line-order matters, and class-attribute order is ignored).

Comment: @Top-Master what are you talking about? `d-flex` and `d-none` work at the smallest screen width. Yes, they are overridden by wider device media queries, but this is not what the OP was having a problem with. the problem is they had `d-flex` instead of `d-none` which was making it display on XS which is not what the OP wanted

Comment: I know what OP meant, but not what your "It's because the `d-flex` is overriding it." means, in fact see [my answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610086/8740349) **Understanding** section (which was originally meant as edit to your answer).

Answer (score 15):

For Bootstrap 4.0 and above:

[image: bootstrap display property]

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/

**Additional information:**

- Hidden only for screen size sm and smaller(like xs) **or** Visible only for screen size md and larger(like lg): **d-none d-md-block**
- Visible only for screen size sm and smaller(like xs) **or** Hidden only for screen size md and larger(like lg): **d-block d-md-none**

Answer (score 0):

OP was trying to hide something on `xs` (extra-small screen-size) with classes:

> ```
> d-sm-none d-md-block d-flex
> ```

But in short, should instead use:

```
d-none d-md-block
```

Continue reading to learn why.

### Understanding

> ###### First the terms; `xs` = extra-small screen-size, `sm` = small screen-size, `md` = medium screen-size, `lg` = large screen-size, `xl` = extra-large screen-size, and so on ...

Looking in Bootstrap 4's CSS source-files, we learn that:

- `d-sm-none` means if screen-width >= `576px` (i.e. greater or equal to smallest-size of `sm` range, which is `576px`), then hide.

  > ```
  > @media (min-width: 576px) {
  >    .d-sm-none {
  >        display: none !important;
  >    }
  > }
  > ```
- `d-md-block` means if screen-width >= `768px`, then show as "`block`".
- Finally, `d-flex` means set DEFAULT display to "`flex`" (I mean, it can NOT override any of above, because it's written in CSS-file before those).

> **Note** that because screen-size >= `xs` condition would always be meet, Bootstrap does NOT provide `d-xs-none`, and we should use `d-none` for that.

### Steps

1. Replace `d-sm-none` with `d-none` (which basically means `d-xs-none`).
2. Leave `d-md-block` as is (if showing on screen-size >= `md` is what you want).
3. Remove `d-flex`, because it overrides `d-none` (since `d-flex` is written in CSS-file after `d-none`, although can never override `d-md-block`).

In short simply use classes:

```
d-none d-md-block
```

### Example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-5">Produkt</div>
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-flex justify-content-start">Cena</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center">Ilość</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-end">Wartość</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/XUSWoSdFcP

**Related:**
[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4/45844579)

Comment: Thank you for interpreting Bootstrap's cryptic documentation. You're the first one I found that's stated the LOGICAL way to use this, "Show for medium or larger" or "Hide for small or smaller."